# DVI to VGA works, DVI to HDMI doesn't with cheap ebay projector

Tags: debian, hdmi

I have a Chinese projector that has a hdmi input which runs fine with a Raspberry Pi, but with a PC it won't! Using DVI to VGA its fine. Zotac ZT 60404 gpu, Exelvan projector. I've tried various PC's running Ubuntu, Puppy and Debian, all the same. The Pi works fine??

I usually tinker with sound so not hot on video.

Can you help, thanks.

Comment: Could you elaborate on "using DVI to VGA it's fine".  That sounds like it's very relavent. What did you use for DVI to VGA... was it just a cable adapter or was it a (powered?) converter?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this in an hw question. As the manufacturer.

Comment: Raspberry Pi has HDMI out, not DVI, yes? So for the computers you are connecting via DVI, are you using the same cable for all of them? Do you know that this cable works?

Comment: Hi, I'm using Debian Stretch, my Projector shows BIOS post, monitor nothing, then halfway through boot, the projector reports no signal and the monitor comes on. Monitor says Nouveau 0000:01:00,0: DRM : DDC responded, but no EDID for DVI-I-1

Comment: I'm using a monitor on one DVI to vga adapter and projector on a DVI to Hdmi

Comment: Yes, the adapters work, the projector shows bios post the monitor doesn't work, then they switch, the monitor displays  Nouveau 0000:01:00,0: DRM : DDC responded, but no EDID for DVI-I-1

Answer (score 0):

You've not given much detail but this sounds like a hardware problem.  DVI plugs can carry multiple different types of signal.  VGA is an analogue signal, it uses different pins on the DVI connector to the digital signal shared by HDMI.  HDMI cannot send VGA, DVI can.

You may need to look at your graphics settings.  If your PC hardware can send a digital signal (most likely for a PC with DVI), then it may be set to output the wrong signal type.

You might need to give more detail about which version of linux you're using to help someone explain how to check the video settings.

Comment: Could be a question of resolution too. Such a projecto would be weak to my MacBook Pro, for instance, but fine in a rpi.

Comment: Resolution is 800 x 600 support for full 1080HD

Comment: xrandr says DVI-I 1 connected to monitor DVI-I 2 disconnected, so is the mini hdmi output